# PN532 RFID Reader IC taking up 4mA even when there is no power applied

Tags: pcb-design, esp32, rfid, pcb-assembly, nfc

I have designed a custom PCB for one of my side projects. PN532 is interfaced with ESP32 over i2c. Goal is to have the system consume current in uAmps range when in deep sleep. I put ESP32 in deep sleep and before doing that, I cut off power to PN532 using NPN transistor. All is working well on a breadboard setup with breakout boards. In deep sleep, current drops to 32uA for the complete system.

But on my custom PCB, current only drops to 4mA in deep sleep. I have put the PCB under thermal camera and PN532 is the only part showing heat signature. I then proceeded to verify that there is no power applied to PN532. So, I am struggling to find why is it pulling 4mA?

I had two theories:

1- The i2c lines between PN532 and ESP32 are probably active for deep sleep mode meaning some part within PN532 is being powered from these lines. But I have checked the lines for voltage and both drop to around 0 in deep sleep.

2- The thermal pin 41 of PN532 is probably not properly grounded (PCB assembly error). I have no way to verify this since thermal pin is the pad below the IC. But could this be the reason for 4mA consumption even when no power is applied?

I am attaching screenshot from the schematic diagram:

[image]

Comment: You might check your 2222A if you are driving it with an ESP32 output during deep sleep.  If the base-emitter has any voltage, there will be some  current .  Even in deep sleep, pull-up resistors (if used) will still be active.

Comment: I2C requires pull ups on both SDA and SCL, where are those?

Comment: @jcaron I am not using pull-up resistors on i2c lines. can it cause a problem like I mentioned? Pulling 4mA when there is no power applied to the IC?

Comment: @johnBirckhead Emitter of 2222A is pulled down (modified the PCB after assembly by adding pull down resistor). Base of 222A is driven by ESP32 and is pulled low before ESP32 enters deep sleep. So there is no voltage across base-emitter. There are no pull-up resistors either.

Comment: @Hamza there are necessarily pull-ups somewhere on the two I2C lines, otherwise it just can't work. If you didn't add any yourself, there must be a pair either in the ESP32 (which are configurable) or in the PN532, or both. In the ESP32 IIRC you can decide which pull-ups are kept active during deep sleep or not (depends on the pins). Don't know about the PN532. From what I gather on your diagram, the ESP32 and the PN532 are on separate boards, right? Did you check that the power draw is indeed on the PN532 board, or is it for the whole setup?

Comment: @jcaron I have checked the PN532 datasheet and there is no mention of pull-ups on the i2c line. On the other hand, ESP32 documentation says that there are internal pull-ups on the i2c lines which are disabled when device enters deep sleep. Also as I mentioned that there was no voltage measured on SDA or SCL when device was in deep sleep but still PN532 was pulling power.

Comment: Let me clarify the setup a little more. There is one PCB which has both ESP32 and PN532. How I know that PN532 is pulling the current is by putting PCB under thermal camera and checking heat signature. I have also checked that there is absolute zero voltage applied across PN532 pins when ESP32 enters deep sleep mode. So only other lines from ESP32 to PN532 are SDA and SCL. But they don't show any voltage at all when device is in deep sleep. What do you think it can be? 

One other thing, I have doubt that PN532 thermal pin might not be grounded. Could this be the cause?

Comment: I don't think the unconnected thermal pad is the issue here, but you may carefully drill a 2 mm hole in the pcb and solder a wire there to verify that. It has nothing to do with the problem, but may I ask, why you use an NPN here? PN532_3V3 will be around 2.7 V only, close to the lower limit of the 532 specification.

Comment: @jens thanks for commenting! I have now verified that connecting thermal pad to ground makes no change in consumption. As for your question, I am using NPN to cut-off source voltage to PN532. How do you say PN532_3V3 will be around 2.7v? I measured and it is coming at about 3.1v.

Comment: I assume the maximum base voltage of the NPN is 3.3 V coming from an ESP32. I expect a Vbe voltage drop of 0.6 V and this gives 2.7 V at PN532_3V3. If you have more there, the transistor does some magic or is made of germanium. Or the whole circuit needs only current in the µA range.

Comment: Things you can do: measure voltage between GND and each of the pins of the PN532 and between 3V3 and each pin. Measure voltage across all resistors (R21, R28, R16…). Cut traces on the PCB to measure current on various lines between the ESP32 part and the PN532 part of the board, including 3V3 (both before and after the transistor), GND, SDA, SCL, PWR. Note that there is always the possibility that the PCB does not exactly match your schematic (either because of a design or manufacturing flaw), so you need to isolate where the fault is before you can fix it. Where do you measure the 4 mA draw?